# Is it Possible to Send libxml Output to a File Handle?

Tags: c, libxml2

This is a simplified version of my earlier [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27768056/libxml-to-stdout-when-using-fastcgi-library), which may have been too situation specific to allow anyone to answer.

Is it possible to send libxml output to a file handle of a previously opened file (E.G. stdin) rather than a file name as used in [these examples](http://www.xmlsoft.org/examples/testWriter.c)?

If it is then it may provide an answer to my earlier query.

Versions etc.
Language: C
Fedora Linux r20
Apache 2.4.10
libxml2

Comment: It has to be possible, search in the libxml documentation.

Comment: Do I really need to add 'I have looked in the libxml documentation and not found the answer' to my question?

Comment: It's not bad if you do. Many people ask questions before reading the documentation.

Answer (score 1):

This is from the same link you posted

```
xmlBufferPtr buf;
/* Create a new XML buffer, to which the XML document will be
 * written */
buf = xmlBufferCreate();
if (buf == NULL) {
    printf("testXmlwriterMemory: Error creating the xml buffer\n");
    return;
}

/* Create a new XmlWriter for memory, with no compression.
 * Remark: there is no compression for this kind of xmlTextWriter */
writer = xmlNewTextWriterMemory(buf, 0);
if (writer == NULL) {
    printf("testXmlwriterMemory: Error creating the xml writer\n");
    return;
}
```

after you finish writing to the memory buffer you can

```
fprintf(file, "%s", buf->content);
```

or if you used `open`

```
write(fd, buf->content, buf->size);
```