# Pretty print with libxml2?

Tags: c++, c, libxml2

Using libxml2.  I can pretty-print the XML into a file by using `xmlSaveFormatFileEnc()`.  But is there a way to do the same thing into a text string or stream?

I'd like to avoid writing the XML out to a file and reading it back in just to get the pretty-print version of the XML.

For the record, what I'm doing now is the following:

```
xmlInitParser();
xmlKeepBlanksDefault(0);
xmlLineNumbersDefault(1);
xmlThrDefIndentTreeOutput(1);
xmlThrDefTreeIndentString("    ");

std::string content = "....."; // do something here to get the XML
xmlDoc * doc = xmlParseDoc((xmlChar*)content.c_str());

xmlSaveFormatFileEnc("output.xml", doc, "utf-8", 1); // pretty print
```

Answer (score 0):

Stolen from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27798232/is-it-possible-to-send-libxml-output-to-a-file-handle):

```
xmlBufferPtr buf;
/* Create a new XML buffer, to which the XML document will be
 * written */
buf = xmlBufferCreate();
if (buf == NULL) {
    std::cerr << "testXmlwriterMemory: Error creating the xml buffer" << std::endl;
    return;
}

/* Create a new XmlWriter for memory, with no compression.
 * Remark: there is no compression for this kind of xmlTextWriter */
writer = xmlNewTextWriterMemory(buf, 0);
if (writer == NULL) {
    std::cerr << "testXmlwriterMemory: Error creating the xml writer" << std::endl;
    return;
}
```

And then, after you have written to the buffer:

```
std::cout << buf->content << std::endl
```

Comment: Something is either missing or not quite right with that code.  Where does the xmlDoc get passed in to be formatted?

Comment: xmlDoc gets passed in betweeen the two snippets of code; you write to buf using xmlDoc, perhaps [xmlNodeDump](http://www.xmlsoft.org/html/libxml-tree.html#xmlNodeDump) might help

Answer (score 0):

just use xmlSaveFormatFileTo() instead of xmlSaveFormatFileEnc()
https://gnome.pages.gitlab.gnome.org/libxml2/devhelp/libxml2-tree.html#xmlSaveFormatFileTo

```
mlBuffer *buffer = xmlBufferCreate();
xmlOutputBuffer *outputBuffer = xmlOutputBufferCreateBuffer(buffer, NULL);
xmlSaveFormatFileTo(outputBuffer, doc, "utf-8", 1);
/* pretty print output in buffer->content */
xmlBufferFree(buffer);
/* outputBuffer has been closed in xmlSaveFormatFileTo */
```

Answer (score 0):

The examples shown in the other answers go down the right path but leave out some important context.

You can, indeed, use the example shown by Sabrina Jewson to generate the xml data as a string without having to write it to the file system.

Before you can use the content of the buffer, you need to make sure that you stop writing the document.

Take the following sample code into consideration:

```
xmlTextWriterPtr writer = NULL;
xmlBufferPtr writer_output = NULL;
std::string encodingVersion = "ISO-8859-1";

// init writer and output pointers.
writer_output = xmlBufferCreate();
writer = xmlNewTextWriterMemory(writer_output, 0);
if(writer == NULL){
    return 1;
}

// start writing document directly in memory
if(xmlTextWriterStartDocument(writer, NULL, encodingVersion.c_str(), NULL) < 0){
    return 1;
}

// Write your xml data
if(xmlTextWriterStartElement(writer, (const xmlChar*)"root") < 0){
    return 1;
}
/* other elements and attributes */
if(xmlTextWriterEndElement(writer) < 0){
    return 1;
}

// Stop writing document
if(xmlTextWriterEndDocument(writer) < 0){
    return 1;
}
if(writer != NULL)
    xmlFreeTextWriter(writer);

// You can now use the output buffer
printf("XML File : \n%s\n", (const char *)writer_output->content);

// free the output buffer
xmlBufferFree(writer_output);
```

This will allow you to write to a buffer which you can then convert to `std::string` if you desire.